# Remove extra characters from diff output

Tags: unix

I have the below output from unix:

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines backup.txt newfile.txt
                                                              > `jjj' int,
```

i need only jjj : int as output.
tried the below didnt work as expected:

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines backup.txt newfile.txt | grep -i '>' |tr -d '[>]'  |sed 's/,//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

suggesting to try `gawk` script:

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines backup.txt newfile.txt | gawk '{print $1 ":" $2}' FPAT="[[:alnum:]]+"
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common reasons for this not working are:

1. Your file is encoded as a non ASCII file, most commonly in `UTF-8`.
   (Save the text files as ASCII.)
2. You are running this in a command shell with colors.
   (Colors are actually ANSI characters and messes up `sed`.)
3. You have encoded your file with a different EOL than used in your *nix OS (`\n`), such as `\r\n` (Windows) or `\r` (MacOS).
4. There are hidden TAB (`\t`) characters in the file.

After you have fixed the above, try this:

```bash
diff -Ewy -r --suppress-common-lines -aB -W 512 file.txt file2.txt | tr -d '[>]'
```